# Renaming index.php in root directory

Tags: .htaccess, root, file-rename

I have two applications on my root directory and im trying to keep them both there but they both have index.php files as a directory index. Is there a way to rename or change one of them so they dont overlap. Or have them both coexist together.

These are the apps im trying to keep under the same directory.

app # 1 https://github.com/wolfcms/wolfcms

app # 2 http://opencart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/upload/

Comment: If they are in the same directory, how are you determining what the user is requesting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without modification to both applications.  Why not?

Both application use htaccess rewrite to map a request to, say,

```
GET /thisPath/SomeFutherContext
```

to execute `DOCROOT/thisPath/.htaccess` which rewrites the request to do an internal redirect to `DOCROOT/thisPath/index.php` which then acts as a central clearing house to process `SomeFutherContext`.

For the two to sit in the same `thispath`, you would need to integrate their `.htaccess` files, have two clearing house entries, say indexwolf.php and indexshop.php, and be able in the .htaccess through some regexp to decode `SomeFutherContext` so that you can dispatch to the right one.

*However*, setting them up so that one is based on `http://yourdomain/wolfcms/` and the other on `http://yourdomain/shop/` is trivial, just follow the install guide for both and install opencart in  `DOCROOT/thisPath/shop/` changing `RewriteBase` in its `.htaccess` file to `RewriteBase /shop/` as it instructs.

BTW,

1. If you are running on a shared service the php_flag directive won't work.  You will need to configure your own php.ini
2. Someone should tell the WolfCMS developers that location headers should conform to RFC 1945 ;-)

## Addendum

If your hosting provider supports a wildcard subdomain mapper (most do by default, so either check your HSPs FAQs or post back here who your hosting provider is), then you can use subdomain e.g. `wolfcms.yourdomain` to separate it from your shop, by adding the following to your docroot `.htaccess` immediately after the `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =wolfcms.yourdomain
RewriteRule ^.*          wolf/$0              [L]
```

You then store WolfCMS in `Docroot/wolf`, and its .htaccess is in `DOCROOT/wolf/.htaccess` with a `RewriteBase /` (not RewriteBase /wolf).

Comment: I already have the shop on my root dir so I cant move at this point since its going to be way too much work. The only thing im trying to do is add the wolf at this point. Can I add wolf in a subdirectory and then show the URLs as root.

Comment: How does your hosting provider support subdomains?  Do you have a cPanel or equiv?  If it does as mine does which is to direct `*.yourdomain` to your DOCROOT then you can do as per my addendum (give me a few mins to post it.)

Comment: Im on a vps and use webadmin as cpanel so I basically have full control over anything including subdomains.

Comment: Then read up on how to use vhost to implement multiple subdomains \([here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/)\), but apart from using vhosts to configure separate docroots for the shop and cms, the soln is as per my addendum.  That's what subdomains are for :)

Comment: So basically I create a sub-domain wolf.domain.com then upload "wolfcms" files in the sub-domain root folder. Or do I upload them under the shop directory and call /wolf/ ?

Comment: look the shop is under `http://yourdomain/` and wolfcms under `http://wolfcms.yourdomain/`.  Why would you want to put the shop under a subdir wolf unless you were _really_ trying to confuse yourself.  Put the cms under wolf and the shop under shop.

Comment: If I were you, I would also move the shop to `shop.youdomain` and do a 301 redirector from `yourdomain` (no subdomain) to `shop.youdomain` so that (i) any existing shop links and google history still work, but that (ii) you don't get into this mess next time :)

Comment: I have the shop on the root and cant really change that. In addition to the shop in my root I have some html pages that Im trying to merge into a cms but would like to keep the same url structure. Thats why im trying to incorporate the wolfcms.

Comment: So you are saying that if I apply your 'addendum' and create the subdomain http://wolfcms.yourdomain/ it will be the same as having it in the root directory ? I will be able to get a URL like this http://yourdomain/about despite being on a subdomain. thanks

Comment: Dony, this would be better on a chatroom, but you don't have enough rep to join one yet.  I am saying that any URI `http://yourdomain/anything` gets passed to the shop app, so how are you going to write any URI which gets pass to wolfcms?  Think about it.  You _**have**_ to have a test which allows URIa to go to the shop and URIb to go the the cms.  What is that?  Using separate subdomains is one simple approach. Doing 20 Qs like this is v inefficient.  Think about what you want.  Give me the info I need to help answer in one shot.  I am not clairvoyant.

Comment: A lot of answers to Qs and no ticks or +1 for the answers means that you will tend not to get answers in future.  Reputation may not be worth much, but its all we get.   :-)

Comment: oh not sure how this place works to be honest..how do I do ticks or +1 ?

Comment: See the FAQ:  reputation is a measure of your contribution to the site and its objectives: by asking good Qs, giving good Ans and contributing to dialogue, etc.  What you do next is to consider what we've talked about; do a bit of your own research and ask focused Qs which help you when you get stuck: make sure that you make it clear what you are asking and provide any clear supporting info so that those more expert can share their knowledge.  Good Qs = more rep.